# Should I be calculating shouldComponentUpdate() a lot in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

I have a ListView that uses Sticky Headers that is having some performance issues. When I console.log in the various render methods I notice that I'm re-rendering...a LOT. Should I be determining whether or not to update using shouldComponentUpdate a lot in react-native vs react? React uses the virtual DOM and can selectively update sections of the DOM so we don't typically run into performance problems like I've seen with react-native.

Does react-native selectively update in the same way that react does or if the render method runs is it ALWAYS rending that component?

**UPDATE:** I added a few shouldComponentUpdate() methods to my ListView row components to selectively update only when needed and it has definitely helped with performance.

**UPDATE 2:** This quote is directly from the react-native documentation's Performance section. http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.36/docs/performance.html

> Similarly, you can implement shouldComponentUpdate and indicate the
>   exact conditions under which you would like the component to
>   re-render.

I was hoping to get a consensus from people who have used react-native (not just react/redux, but react-native) to know if they too find themselves using shouldComponentUpdate() a lot to improve performance.

Comment: Could you provide example code to see how you are using the ListView ?

Comment: Proprietary code, but each row in the list has 2 sub-components containing images and svgs. [[image component] text [svg component][svg component]]

Comment: You shouldn't have to use that function at all, just update state of component you want to re render

Comment: ...ya Peter, but I'm using redux and my components are connected to containers. When state changes they render...that's kinda the point of react/redux. I'm just trying to determine if there are good performance gains from using shouldComponentUpdate to selectively re-render only when needed. Curious if this is common and/or a best-practice

Comment: The connect function of redux already useless renders, so you shouldn't have to worry about that method